# React call a function inside return to insert a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am trying to create a function in my class to avoid writing the same code multiple times.  Currently I have my 3 bookshelves and have to write the same code between the Bookshelf tags 3 times.  I would like to be able to call a function instead to make the code look more lean.  This is my current code for 1 Bookshelf which works fine:

```js
class BookApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Currently Reading'}>                    
                **{this.state.allBooks.filter((book) => {
                return book.shelf === 'currentlyReading';
                }).map((b) => {
                return (
                    <Book
                    key={b.id}
                    currentShelf={b.shelf}
                    clicked={(event) => {this.moveHandler(event, b.id)}}
                    bookTitle={b.title}
                    bookAuthor={b.authors}
                    backgroundImage={`url(${b.imageLinks.thumbnail})`}
                    />
                )
                })}**
            </Bookshelf>
        </div>
        )
    }   
}
```

I tried adding a function that does the same thing and calling that function inside { }, but it doesn't return my  components.  Any help is much appreciated!

```js
class BookApp extends React.Component {

    filterBooks(shelf) {
            this.state.allBooks.filter((book) => {
            return book.shelf === shelf;
            }).map((b) => {
            return (
                <Book
                    key={b.id}
                    currentShelf={b.shelf}
                    clicked={(event) => {this.moveHandler(event, b.id)}}
                    bookTitle={b.title}
                    bookAuthor={b.authors}
                    backgroundImage={`url(${b.imageLinks.thumbnail})`}
                />
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Currently Reading'}>                    
                {this.filterBooks('currentlyReading')}
            </Bookshelf>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Want to Read'}>                    
                {this.filterBooks('wantToRead')}
            </Bookshelf>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Read'}>                    
                {this.filterBooks('read')}
            </Bookshelf>
        </div>
        )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You have only return map array but you didn't return `filterBooks` itself. Please  return`filterBooks` function and see it working or not!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code that I have edit. Simply return the `filterList` collection from `filterBooks` function.

```js
class BookApp extends React.Component {

    filterBooks(shelf) {
           let filterList = this.state.allBooks.filter((book) => {
            return book.shelf === shelf;
            }).map((b) => {
            return (
                <Book
                    key={b.id}
                    currentShelf={b.shelf}
                    clicked={(event) => {this.moveHandler(event, b.id)}}
                    bookTitle={b.title}
                    bookAuthor={b.authors}
                    backgroundImage={`url(${b.imageLinks.thumbnail})`}
                />
            )
        })
        return filterList;
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Currently Reading'}>                    
                {this.filterBooks('currentlyReading')}
            </Bookshelf>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Want to Read'}>                    
                {this.filterBooks('wantToRead')}
            </Bookshelf>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Read'}>                    
                {this.filterBooks('read')}
            </Bookshelf>
        </div>
        )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This works!  Thank you so much.  I actually had a hunch it had something to do with me not returning something in the function

Answer (score 1):

simply put a return before "this.state.allBooks" but as you write react and the idea behind Components in react it would be better if you move this logic inside Bookshelf Component.

```js
class BookApp extends React.Component {

    filterBooks(shelf) {
            return this.state.allBooks.filter((book) => {
            return book.shelf === shelf;
            }).map((b) => {
            return (
                <Book
                    key={b.id}
                    currentShelf={b.shelf}
                    clicked={(event) => {this.moveHandler(event, b.id)}}
                    bookTitle={b.title}
                    bookAuthor={b.authors}
                    backgroundImage={`url(${b.imageLinks.thumbnail})`}
                />
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Currently Reading'}>                    
                {this.filterBooks('currentlyReading')}
            </Bookshelf>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Want to Read'}>                    
                {this.filterBooks('wantToRead')}
            </Bookshelf>
            <Bookshelf shelfTitle={'Read'}>                    
                {this.filterBooks('read')}
            </Bookshelf>
        </div>
        )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your solution works as well! And yes I agree with you it might make more sense to put it into the bookshelf component, but I have 2 containers where I am managing state, and I'm trying to keep it to that, which is why I have it here.  Thanks though!